# Getting Sheet to Modify It with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to delete a row from my sheet via Apps Script. I've been searching for answers. The documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deleteRow(Integer)) uses `getActiveSpreadsheet()` method, but it always returns `null` to me. I don't understand how 'active spreadsheet' and 'non-active spreadsheet' work. Is there any way that I can get my spreadsheet by ID instead? Or do you have any other solution? I read in some parts that there is 'bound script' but I don't know how it works.

P.S. I used to use these methods to append and update my sheet. Could have it been expired so that I can't find the official documentation?

```
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.append(resource,spreadsheetId,range,optionalArgs);
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(resource,spreadsheetId,range,optionalArgs);
```

Comment: The Active Spreadsheet is your current document. [This documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet) may help. What you can define by ID are the current/active sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will delete the first row.

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById('Id').getSheetByName('SheetName').deleteRow(1);
```